# Customies entries list is only visible with allowAdminChanges=true?

Tags: entries, admin

[image]

Running Craft 4.2.8, I only see this when allowAdminChanges=true, otherwise this Customize icon is gone. How come?

This is not the case in latest Craft 3. Or is there some caching problem here? Clearing caches doesn't make a difference though. Seems like an odd choice, this settings is AFAIK per-user and is merely a UI adaption.

Answer (score 1):

It was never possible to customise the element index source settings per user; it was always a "global" setting that changed the sources for all users.

The only difference between Craft 3 and Craft 4 is that in Craft 4, the settings are tracked in the [project config](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/project-config.html), instead of only being saved to the database. This is why it's no longer possible to change these settings in environments where `allowAdminChanges` is `false`.

The good news is that in the upcoming Craft 4.3 release, individual users will be able to customise the visible table columns via a new "View" menu in the element index. Essentially, this will finally allow per-user index source configurations, while keeping the "default" settings in version control alongside other parts of the Craft CMS schema.

**Edit:** Craft 4.3.0 has been released, with the new "View" menu in element indexes.

More info: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/discussions/11355

Comment: Aha, it was never per-user? I wasn't aware, then it makes sense. Thank you very much!

Comment: Exactly – I'll revise the answer to make that clearer.